# Zurb Foundation is overriding my custom cancel button's background when disabled

Tags: button, zurb-foundation

I added a new class called cancel for our cancel button.

from _settings.scss

```
$cancel-button-bg-color: $charcoal;
$cancel-button-bg-hover: lighten($cancel-button-bg-color, 20%);
```

from _buttons.scss

```
.cancel {
  background: $cancel-button-bg-color;
  &:hover {
    background: $cancel-button-bg-hover;
  }
}
```

The color I assigned to the cancel button is #555555 or $charcoal. The cancel button's background color gets displayed properly. The hover background color is being displayed fine too.

Now for the problem. When I add the "disabled" class to the cancel button, the background color that gets applied is $primary-color with opacity. I still would like to have a background color of $charcoal but a little lighter like opacity of 50%.

Another problem I see is that when I click on the Cancel button, the button's background changes to the $primary-color.

I'm not sure if I'm doing the right approach. I tried using the $secondary-color but was wondering why it's not changing the background of my button with a secondary class assigned to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of CSS [Specificity](http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html). Foundation's "disabled" styling is `button[disabled]` which is an attribute and an element selector. It trumps `.cancel` which is only a class selector.

Try

```
.cancel, .cancel[disabled] {
  background: $cancel-button-bg-color;
  &:hover {
    background: $cancel-button-bg-hover;
  }
}
```

Comment: I got it working last night too but I wrote it a little different - http://pastebin.com/YQU27YA9